# Conversion from Spherical Coordinates to Cartesian Coordinates aligned along arbitrary polar axis

Tags: rotations, spherical-coordinates

I have spherical coordinates $w = (\theta, \phi)$ such that $\theta$ is the angle between $w$ and the polar axis (let's assume $z$ is up).

Assuming $w$ is a unit vector, the conversion to cartesian coordinates is:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= \cos(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\
y &= \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\
z &= \cos(\theta)
\end{align}
\right.
$$

I'd like to transform $w$ such that its polar axis lies on an arbitrary vector $n$, and then convert to cartesian coordinates.  The end goal is to generate a hemisphere point cloud about the normal vector $n$, but when generating random variables, it is most convenient to initialize them in $z$-up space.

Rodriguez's formulation via [Rotating one 3d-vector to another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293116/rotating-one-3-vector-to-another) makes sense if we are going from Cartesian->Cartesian but is there a more efficient way to do it, maybe rotating the Spherical coordinates directly before converting to cartesian coords?

Thanks.

Comment: Standard names for your spherical coordinates:  $\theta$ is *colatitude* and $\phi$ is *longitude*.