# Does this orthogonal matrix parametrization have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, terminology, orthogonal-matrices

Given two linearly independent unit vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}$, the matrix
$$
P(u, v) = I + 2 vu^{T}-\frac{(u+v)(u+v)^{T}}{1+u^Tv}
$$
is the unique special orthogonal matrix that brings $u$ to coincide with $v$ and reduces to the identity when projected to the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}(u,v)$. That is:
$$P^T(u,v) P(u,v) = I$$
$$P(u,v)u = v$$
$$P(u,v)w = w\quad \forall w \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}\ /\ u^Tw = 0 \wedge v^Tw = 0$$
(Note that for $n > 3$ not all special orthogonal matrices can be expressed in this way.)

I've never encountered this parametrization before today. Does it have a name?

Comment: are you sure of this? If $u^Tv=-1$ it does not seem defined..

Comment: @Exodd then they are not *linearly independent*, but parallel and in opposite directions.

Comment: @mathreadler I didn't read "unit" vector

Comment: However, they are similar to  Givens rotations